# Word to describe "quick-witted streetchild"

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, word-choice

I'm talking of a certain wit that is characteristic of streetboys and streetchildren in general. I'm not sure if streetchildren is the best way to describe these kids. That might not be very common in developed countries, where few people are homeless or deprived of education and other basic rights like how it is the case in the Third world.

On a more general note, I'm referring to children that are not too pampered and have learned to get on by themselves. Clever, fast, handy, quick to learn, and with a sharp tongue. Think Dicken's Artful Dodger.

In contrast to a spoonfed crybaby who has their parents by their side at all times. Pardon the heavily stereotypical descriptions, but that was just to get my point across. And please do try coming up with something more sophisticated than "street-smart" or the like.

A sample to give you an idea of what I'm getting at:

> It was amusing to see how ***he*** gave out instructions to the others his age labouring and taking orders. His words were ***slick***, typical of a ***know-all streetsmarty***. The big-eyed kid had been trudging past the shady-looking resturant when ***that boy with a shabby hat*** whistled at spotting him. "Ye, looking for work, huh?" He jumped down onto the road and made his way towards the trembling child of four.

Comment: Single-word requests are required to provide a sample sentence showing how the word will be used....  Perhaps your description works as is:   “The little Artful Dodger snatched the watch off my wrist so expertly that I didn’t notice it was gone until I got back to the hotel.”

Comment: @Jim I was just thinking about it this day. I don't have a specific context in mind.

Comment: Try to think of one whose meaning helps to capture the essence of the word you’re looking for.  For example my sentence above, as opposed to “The [witty streetchild] walked across the street.”  Which tells us nothing.

Comment: Your example suggests a predator ambushing smaller prey. Your question emphasizes "wit" and sleight-of-hand. Are you looking for a single word that suggests danger, intelligence and dexterity? Must the word only apply to street urchins?

Comment: [*Street-smart*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/street-smart) covers a lot of what you're looking for, but it doesn't necessarily suggest wit or a silver tongue.

Comment: @sippybear I just whipped up whatever sentence I could where the witty streetchild description fits, just for the sake of it. Of course, it's not perfect.

Comment: 'Witty' usually means 'humorous'. Do you mean it in the sense of 'quick-witted'?

Comment: @SohaFarhinPine Your sample sentence should include a blank for where the requested word fits. The Single-word-requests tag also requires you to show what research you have done and the 'more info' page also explains *how* you might research it. For example, you have referenced the Artful Dodger, have you looked up 'artful' in a thesaurus?

Comment: ["Streetwise" or its synonyms](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/streetwise) might work, though maybe that's too similar to "street smart" which you have eliminated for some reason.

Comment: There is no reason that you can't use *Artful Dodger* as a common noun, with the assumption that the reference will be known. Which points back to the first comment here.

Answer (score 2):

**savvy** (adj.)

> Having or demonstrating common sense; knowledgeable, experienced;
> knowing, shrewd. OED

> Knowledge gained by actually doing or living through something
> [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/savvy)

> If you describe someone as savvy, you think that they show a lot of
> practical knowledge. [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/savvy)

> Marked by practical hardheaded intelligence
>
> Most English words stem directly from other European languages, like
> French and Latin. Not **savvy**. It comes from the West Indies, a twist on
> the French savez vous? — “Do you know?” Savvy was first recorded in
> its adjective form in 1905. [vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/savvy)

---

> This canine take on Dickens's Artful Dodger is a **savvy** New York
> City guide for little Oliver. [Christopher Lucas; *Top Disney*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Top_Disney/Si2GDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=artful%20dodger%20savvy&pg=PA117&printsec=frontcover)

> Contrary to the *television generation,* the *net generation* (or
> *N-Geners*) were portrayed as *hungry for expression, discovery, and their own self-development.* Positioned against all the old criticisms
> of the television generation, they were **savvy**, *self-reliant,
> analytical, creative, inquisitive, accepting of diversity, socially
> conscious,* and *globally oriented*. [D. T. Cook; *The SAGE
> Encyclopedia of Children and Childhood Studies*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_SAGE_Encyclopedia_of_Children_and_Ch/jNzBDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=savvy%20self-sufficient%20children&pg=PT1458&printsec=frontcover)

> We traced the development of the sovereign self through alienation,
> from naïve will to **savvy** wit, in the consciousnesses of Richard II and
> Falstaff. [J. A. Bates; *Hegel and Shakespeare on Moral
> Imagination*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Hegel_and_Shakespeare_on_Moral_Imaginati/stU5XG70AHkC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22savvy%20wit%22&pg=PA244&printsec=frontcover)

> Some of us think we're only really smart if we have some kind of
> advanced degree in an important field; that it doesn't really count to
> be clever or "street smart."
> But smart is as smart does—the official
> definition of the word includes "**savvy**" as well as "brainy."
> [Jenifer Madson; *Head to Heart*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Head_to_Heart/Z5RaBQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=savvy%20brainy&pg=PA47&printsec=frontcover)